# VLC stops after playing a song

Tags: fedora, vlc-media-player, playlists

I'm playing from `My Music` that's not from playlist but from the media in `~\Music`

In Windows it goes on playing the second item in the directory tree after the first is done, but in Fedora VLC stops the music when the current song reaches the end.

I tried to search in Preferences in  All Settings, but couldn't find anything related, or I might miss the correct option.

I want it to continue playing the folder, that is the music library, without me having to click `n` for next song shortcut.

Comment: In Ubuntu I select all the items in a folder, right-click and choose Open with VLC: all the items are added to the play-list and play in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

VLC cannot add similar files when you play a certain file in OS X as well.So i wonder VLC does not support automaticlly adding similar files.

I remember SMplayer in Fedora should support this.In Preference-playlist,there is a option about adding similar files to current playlist created for the file you open.